# MCP3008 only returns 0 values

Tags: mcp3008

I have a MCP3008 that is connected to 2 LDRs, one on CH0 one on CH7, the other 6 CH are grounded. When running the simpletest.py of the Adafruit MCP library I get back 0 from every pin. I measured CH0 and CH7 with a Osci and know they do get values. I checked the jumpers with a multimeter; they are all working. My pins are connected for software SPI meaning CLK, In and Out of the MCP with GPIO 11, 10, 9 and and CS with GPIO 8. SPI is enabled in the Raspberry Config.

Comment: Need a clear photo of the actual connections and a schematic showing the intended connections.

Comment: If you feed the MCP3008 a known voltage on one pin can you read that?